# django-multilingual-ng / Django 1.1.1 incompatibility?

Tags: django, incompatibility, django-multilingual

I am getting "cannot import name connections" exception while trying to use django-multilingual-ng 0.1.20 with Django 1.1.1.

The exception comes from the line 15 of query.py where it tries to:

```
from django.db import connections, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
```

Is it not compatible with Django 1.1.1? Does anybody tried this combination and have any suggestions?

Thanks.

--
oMat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-multilingual-ng is a branch of django-multilingual to [make it](http://github.com/ojii/django-multilingual-ng/blob/master/README) compatible with django 1.2 which has support for multidb, so you are out of luck.

You can try with django-multilingual or just wait less than a week and start coding with the newest and shiniest just baked last django release (currently in rc1).

Hope this helps.